# Identity not finding my User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromBody] RegisterDto model)
 {
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user == null)
       return Content("Email id not exist");
    var passwordResetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var passwordResetUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { id = user.Id, token = passwordResetToken }, Request.Scheme);
    await _messageService.Send(model.Email, "Password reset", $"Click <a href=\"" + passwordResetUrl + "\">here</a> to reset your password");
    return Content("Check your email for a password reset link");
 }
```

i am debugging this method and i am passing my email id from postman and email id is in my DB but still it is not able to get my user back.Can u please tell me the error what i am doing.

regards

Comment: If you manually connect to the database (via SQL Server Management Studio, or similar) and perform a select on the relevant users table, does the email that you are passing in via Postman appear in the list or results?

Comment: This sounds like a problem within your `_userManager` rather than having anything to do with identity server